# How do i change settings of selected images from a folder?

Tags: vb.net

First : I'm French

So I'm kind of a begginer in coding, I'm in my first year learning and I have a job to do which is : Make a VBNET application that Import a folder full of pictures (I dont know how to select and store the folder by the way)

Then change the pictures settings (like the name, the date it was taken,the autor) and then chose a selected folder and copy the new images with the new settings, can you guys please help me ?
Here is what I already have :

```
Public Class FrmStart
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dialog As New FolderBrowserDialog()
        If DialogResult.OK = dialog.ShowDialog Then
            txtboxImport.Text = dialog.SelectedPath
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: This task might seem trivial but it's not. Setting the PropertyItem requires something like this: [Image::SetPropertyItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-image-setpropertyitem). But you also have to know which format supports which property tag. The Shell extension library allows you to interact with the Image objects metadata. If you know how to use the Shell interfaces. You probably want to look around an find a NuGet package that already provides these functionalities.

Comment: there is example on accessing [`Image.PropertyItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.propertyitems) here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/041ae9d1-cd71-4dda-91db-ff62c5c9a3d6/editing-the-tag-of-an-image-file?forum=vbgeneral